# How to Cancel SQL open

Tags: c#, sql, connection

Right now, my server is down that has my DB on it. So as it stands, when I try to open the connection to the database, it hangs for a good 20 seconds on the sql.open() method. It works fine when the server is up and running, but Is there a way to interrupt the opening of the connection if the user chooses to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can `ping` the server to ensure it is up.
[More information here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/109427/How-to-PING-Server-in-C)

Comment: How does pinging the server solves OP's question `Is there a way to interrupt the opening of the connection`?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: before opening connection make a ping, get the result & allow user to open connections accordingly.

Comment: Sorry Mangesh, it doesn't answer my question. If the user has a slow internet connection, opening the connection might take some additional time. I'd like to give them the opportunity to cancel. You make a good point, but it doesn't actually answer the question at hand.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage it still doesn't solves OP's problem. What, for example, if server goes down right after your ping was succesful and you're trying to connect? Don't reinvent the bicycle, there is much more simple and common way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `OpenAsync` method instead of `Open`. It has `CancellationToken` as argument which can be used to request that the operation be abandoned before the connection timeout elapses.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204855%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference for OpenAsync.

In the case of async opening you should handle `StateChange` event of connection to catch the moment when connection will be actually opened.